# Extracting more than one Video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multivideo stream and i want to extract that both video that are encapsulated inside the container stream.
Any idea how should i extract two video using ffmpeg?

Comment: What has this to do with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for the -map option. you can create multiple output definition like below

```
  ffmpeg -i muxed.mp4 -c:v copy -map 0:0 video1.m4v -c:v copy -map 0:1 video2m4v -c:a copy -map 0:2 audio1.m4a -c:s copy -map 0:3 subtitle1.srt -c:s copy -map 0:4 subtitle2.srt
```

each output is define by a set of parameters that start with the -c:v option

Comment: Please define... open a question on super users and add the whole ffmpeg -i output of the input file and the whole command line and result you got